# Why doesn't input call work in my asm code?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

I have tried the following code for block transfer of data in assembly language. The code works fine for Non-overlapped case but I'm not able to type the input to get the 'count' value.

```
section .data       
    name db 'John'  ;initialize name array  
    name_len equ $-name ;initialize name length 
    surname db 'Smith'  ;initialize surname array
    sur_len equ $-surname   ;intialize surname length
    tot equ name_len + sur_len  ;initialize total length
    msg1 db "Initial name is: "     ;message 1
    msg1_len equ $-msg1         ;length of message
    msg2 db 0xa,"Non-overlapped transfer: " ;message2
    msg2_len equ $-msg2
    msg3 db "Overlapped String transfer: "
    msg3_len equ $-msg3
    endl db 0xa
    endlen equ $-endl
    steps db 0                   ;Stores the value length-count
    msg4 db "Enter 1,2 or 3"
    msg4_len equ $-msg4
    msg5 db "Enter the count "
    msg5_len equ $-msg5
section .bss
    choice resb 1                    ;for non-overlapped or overlapped
    a resb 1                         ;storing final length in overlapped case
    count resb 1                     ;Count is the number of letters which are overlapped
section .text
    global _start       ;linker
_start:
beg:
    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,msg4
    mov edx,msg4_len
    int 0x80    

    mov eax,4
    mov ecx,endl
    mov edx,endlen
    int 0x80

    mov eax,3
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,choice
    mov edx,1
    int 0x80

    cmp byte[choice],0x33
    je exit
    cmp byte[choice],0x32
    je overcall
    cmp byte[choice],0x31
    je noncall
noncall:
    call non
    jmp exit
overcall:   
    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,msg5
    mov edx,msg5_len
    int 0x80

    mov eax,3
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,count                ;I can't input any value for count in the terminal
    mov edx,1
    int 0x80

    sub byte[count],0x30
    mov al,name_len
    add al,sur_len
    sub al,[count]      
    mov [a],al
    call over
    jmp exit
exit:
    mov eax,1       ;syscall for exit
    int 0x80        ;call kernel

non:
    mov eax,4       ;syscall for print
    mov ecx,msg1        ;move address of msg1 to ecx
    mov edx,msg1_len    ;move msg1 length to edx
    int 0x80        ;call kernel    

    mov eax,4       ;syscall for print
    mov ecx,name        ;move address of name to ecx
    mov edx,name_len    ;move name length to edx
    int 0x80        ;call kernel        

    mov esi,name        ;move address of name to esi
    mov edi,surname     ;move surname address to edi
    add esi,name_len    ;add name_length to move to last byte
    mov ebx,sur_len     ;move length of surname to ebx
up:
    mov eax,[edi]       ;move character of surname to eax
    mov [esi],eax       ;move character to last of name
    inc esi         ;increment esi
    inc edi         ;increment edi
    dec ebx         ;decrement count
    jnz up          ;jumpif not zero to up

    mov eax,4       ;syscall for print
    mov ecx,msg2        ;move address of name to ecx
    mov edx,msg2_len    ;move name length to edx
    int 0x80        ;call kernel    

    mov eax,4       ;syscall for print
    mov ecx,name        ;move address of name to ecx
    mov edx,tot     ;move total length to edx
    int 0x80        ;call kernel    

    mov eax,4
    mov ecx,endl
    mov edx,endlen
    int 0x80
    ret

over:
    mov eax,4
    mov ecx,msg3
    mov edx,msg3_len
    int 0x80

    xor rax,rax
    mov rsi,name
    mov rdi,surname
    mov al,name_len
    sub al,[count]
    mov [steps],al
    add rsi,rax
    mov ecx,sur_len
    xor rax,rax 

upp:
    mov al,[rdi]
    mov [rsi],al
    inc rsi
    inc rdi
    dec ecx
    jnz upp

    mov eax,4
    mov ecx,name
    mov edx,[a]
    int 0x80

    mov eax,4
    mov ecx,endl
    mov edx,endlen
    int 0x80
    ret
```

The program just prints something garbage after choosing the option as 2.

Here's the output:

```
Enter 1,2 or 3
2
Enter the count Overlapped String transfer: JohnSmithInitial name is: 
Non-overlapped Smithfer: Overlapped String transfer: 
*Enter 1,2 or 3Enter the count 2/�
```

The code works fine if I just initialize the count value instead of accepting it from the user

Comment: You actually type `2` followed by `enter` and you leave that enter (line feed) in the input buffer so that's what reading the `count` will return.

Comment: Probably not causing you problems in this code, but you tagged this x86-64 (and actually use 64-bit registers a couple times), but all the rest of the code is using 32-bit system calls and even 32-bit addressing modes!!  [What is the explanation of this x86 Hello World using 32-bit int 0x80 Linux system calls from \_start?](//stackoverflow.com/q/45052162)  That will break as soon as you try to use any stack addresses that way, because (unlike static data), the address of stack memory is above 2^32, outside the low 4GiB of memory.  Addressing modes will fault, int 0x80 will return `-EFAULT`

Comment: @Jester In that case how should I give the input?

Comment: @AnishKoulgi Read until you encounter a line feed or end of input.